# Error: A value of type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create the list of icons but i am able to create. please help

[image]

I added square brackets but it shows Error: Expected an identifier, but got ']'.enter image description here.

[image]

I am doing Angela yu course ig thats outdated but i cant find solution in the documentation as well

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either try this

```dart
Row(
children:scoreKeeper,
)
```

or this

```dart
Row(
children:[
//your other widgets

...scoreKeeper // ... is called spread operator
],
),
```

if you want to add gap in it then you can try this code

```dart
Row(
            children: [
             
              for (final icon in scoreKeeper) ...[
                icon,
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                )
              ]
            ],
          )
```

or you can add gap in the `scoreKeeper` list directly like this

```dart
List<Widget> scoreKeeper=[
Icon(Icons.check),
const SizedBox(width:10),
Icon(Icons.close),
];
```

You can read more about spread operator at [dart documentation](https://dart.dev/language/collections#spread-operators)

Comment: okay it worked thank you so much is there any other way to contact you?

Comment: checkout the updated answer there are other ways too to add gap in it.

Comment: Okay sir can you check your instagram dm ?